Ceph Manager Daemon: SMB Module is not available
I currently have a Ceph Cluster in version 18.2.2 (reef). It runs an NFS-Ganesha cluster with some NFS exports. I wanted to deploy an SMB cluster (as documented at https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/smb/). Unfortunately, the smb module cannot be found/activated. Via ceph mgr module ls I get the result: smb on (after I had activated the module with ceph mgr module enable smb --force), but without any functionality. The cluster was rolled out via cephadm and runs in containers. Unfortunately, no clear contribution can be found. My hope was to get around CTDB and Ceph. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the documentation and would be grateful for clarification.
I saw the note on the official documentatiom, but I couldn't do much with it: The smb module currently requires cephadm orchestration. It doesn't work without orchestration.
Thanks & Regards
Leo

The first note on the page you referred to states:

This document is for a development version of Ceph.

That's why you can't find it for the currently active releases (Pacific, Quincy, Reef) And although the Squid docs contain the smb service, trying to enable it results in a warning:
# ceph mgr module enable smb
Error ENOENT: all mgr daemons do not support module 'smb', pass --force to force enablement

So I wouldn't expect it to work properly yet. I don't have a proper samba config to apply, but at least the orchestrator tries something:
# ceph orch apply smb test-smb rados://.smb/tango/scc.toml
Scheduled smb.test-smb update...

I see that it downloads the required image, but that's how far I get. Maybe it actually does work for you.
